# How to publish a Pub/Sub message with a Supplier bean?

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to publish a Pub/Sub message in Spring according to the Google documentation (see https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/spring#publishing-messages-using-stream-binder). The only problem is that I am new to Spring Framework and I have no idea of how to turn this example into something that I can use. That is, a method that allows me to send a specific message from a service to the Pub/Sub topic.

```java
// Create an output binder to send messages to `topic-one` using a Supplier bean.
@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> sendMessageToTopicOne() {
  return () ->
      Flux.<Message<String>>generate(
              sink -> {
                try {
                  Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  // Stop sleep earlier.
                }

                Message<String> message =
                    MessageBuilder.withPayload("message-" + rand.nextInt(1000)).build();
                LOGGER.info(
                    "Sending a message via the output binder to topic-one! Payload: "
                        + message.getPayload());
                sink.next(message);
              })
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

How can I write a method that allows me to send a specific message (lets say a 'String') to my Pub/Sub topic that can be called from a service?

Comment: Use the Java libraries, not the spring integration.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I had some problems with the first approach in the Google article (without the Spring integration). My goals was to send an object through Pub/Sub. However, I did not manage to serialize it without errors and Spring's integration can handle that for me. That is why I intend to use it along with the Message and MessageBuilder classes.

Comment: Hi @FOR_SCIENCE, for your requirement you can try the steps given in this [documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/#initial).Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now using an old and deprecated method with Channels, but it works fine so far.